# Implement restaurant rating system in FireStore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Fire Store documentation [says trigger maybe called multiple times.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#limitations_and_guarantees) To solve this problem, it says we should make sure the trigger is idempotent.

In another section it suggests we [use triggers to update the average ratings.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation#solution_cloud_functions) But the example code shown looks like not idempotent.

What's the right way to implement the trigger so that the average rating is always correct? Or there is other better way?